# Bubble Sort Gone Wrong

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

## Bubble sort

Hi all, after learning how the Bubble-Sorting Algorithm works (By comapring two adjacent elements and swapping them out when necessary), I tried to code the problem. But I've been unable to do so.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int swap(int a, int b);

int main() {
  // swap(3,4);
  int array[20], n,;
  printf("Enter the value of integers to be added to the matrix: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter the integers:");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }

  swap(array[1], array[2]);

  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
      swap(array[j], array[j + 1]);}
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int swap(int a, int b) {
  int temp = 0;
  temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

This is the code that I've come up with. I think that in the loop that I'm not traversing the array when I'm comparing the adjacent elements,if not how to traverse an array whilst comparing elements. I'd really appreciate if you could help me understand where it is that I'm making a mistake and how to rectify it.

Kind Regards
X

This is the output that I'm getting

```
 make -s
 ./main
Enter the value of integers to be added to the matrix: 5
Enter the integers:5 4 3 2 1
3 44 53 42 31 20 1
```

Comment: First of all, since you enter `n` values into your array, then `n` will be an invalid index (with an indeterminate value). Your sorting loop `for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)` will use `n` as index (in the last iteration then `j + 1` will be equal to `n`).

Comment: And you really need two loops, one nested inside the other, for a bubble-sort to work.

Comment: Your `swap` function does swap those variables. However they are *copies* of the variables passed, and the locally swapped values will be discarded.

Comment: While the other comments do point out real problems with your code, there is a more fundamental problem: You didn’t post your actual code. The code you posted has a syntax error (the comma after `n` in `int array[20], n,;` is invalid), so it will not even compile. Also the code you posted does not print the array back out, so it cannot have printed the output you say it printed. You will get better help if you carefully copy and paste the actual code you compiled and ran.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void    ft_swap(int *i, int *x)
{
    int tmp;
    
    tmp = *i;
    *i = *x;
    *x = tmp;
}

int is_sorted(int *ary, int len)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < len - 2)
    {
        if (ary[i] > ary[i + 1])
            return (1);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

int sort_array(int *ary, int len)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (is_sorted(ary, len) == 1)
    {
        if (ary[i] > ary[i + 1])
            ft_swap(&ary[i], &ary[i + 1]);
        i++;
        if(i == (len - 1))
            i = 0;
    }
    return (0);
}

int *argv_to_array(int len, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int *ary;

    i = 0;
    ary = malloc(sizeof(int) * len - 1);
    while(i < len - 1)
    {
        ary[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
        i++;
    }
    return(ary);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int *ary;

    if(argc > 1)
    {
        i = 0;
        ary = argv_to_array(argc, argv);
        sort_array(ary, argc);
        while(i < argc - 1)
        {
            printf("%i ", ary[i]);
            i++;
        }
        free(ary);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Your swap function is wrong. This is how I would code it. But there are better ways. For sorting algos( and many other things) list are much better and easier to work with, if you get into it.